# Going through a list and add an attribute if objects have same id

Tags: java

I have a User class that has several attributes including Id. What I want to know is which would be the best way to go through this list and add the time attribute into the TotalTime if the users have the same Id.

I tried a double for loop comparing each object kind of a C (language) double loop to go through the list and add. But I don't think that is the correct approach in Java and I think that there may be methods that will make it easier as well to have a more neat code.

I have this class:

```
public class User {
private String Date;
private String Time;
private String Status;
private String Id;
private String Duration;
private Long Seconds;
private Long Totaltime;
}
```

I know I can use something like the following to iterate through it.
I was using two for loops but I am quite sure that it's not the correct approach in Java.

```
for (User user : users) {
for (User user : users) {
.....
.....

}
}
```

Doesn't seem the way to go. I want to find a nice and simple way to do it. Please help (I'm very new with Java)

I want to add in one attribute of the User (Totaltime) the sum of all the time that the users with the same Id spent online (Seconds attribute).

Comment: I'd put all values in a hash map: `Map<string, User>`. The key (string) is the id and the value (User) is the user. Here is a good explanation: https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_hashmap.asp

Comment: In which of all the users with the same id would you like to store the total time?

Comment: On all of the users with the same Id, I want them all to have the attribute TotalTime.@DanielMesejo Thanks, everyone for the help. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Following the advise of @yahavi you could use [Collectors.groupingBy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function):

```
ArrayList<User> users = new ArrayList<User>() {{
    add(new User("1", 2L));
    add(new User("2", 2L));
    add(new User("1", 3L));

}};

Map<String, Long> result = users.stream()
                .collect(groupingBy(User::getId, summingLong(User::getTime)));
```

**Output**

```
{1=5, 2=2}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, you can use a `Map<String, User>` where the first String argument is your id, and de second, your object.

```
Map<String, User> users = new HashMap<>();
```

to populate your list:

```
users.put(key, value);
```

So, you cand do this to find your key:

```
if(users.containsKey(idUser)){
    users.get(idUser).setTotalTime(1000);
}
```